Vue-Router render the component but doesn't change the url
import { createMemoryHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";
import { AuthUser } from "../../auth/user";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component : () => import("../components/Home/Home.vue"),
    beforeEnter : (to, from, next)=>{
      if(!AuthUser()){
        next({path : "/signup"})
      }else{
        next()
        return ""
      }
    }
  },
  {
    path: "/signup",
    component : () => import("@/components/Signup/Signup.vue"),
  }
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createMemoryHistory(),
  routes,
});

export default router
 

I don't know why when I open "/" , the component signup it's show but url "http://localhost:3000/ " doesn't change at all.
The component it's show perfectly, it's the url the problem.
AuthUser always return false for now.

This happens because you use createMemoryHistory() as a history mode which is not browser-compatible but used for tests and server-side rendering, you need to use createWebHistory() instead which leverages the browser's history.
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from 'vue-router';
import { AuthUser } from "../../auth/user";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component : () => import("../components/Home/Home.vue"),
    beforeEnter : (to, from, next) => {
      if (!AuthUser()) {
        next({path : "/signup"});
      } else {
        next();
      }
    }
  },
  {
    path: "/signup",
    component : () => import("@/components/Signup/Signup.vue"),
  }
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
});

export default router;

